# Tight-binding model parameters fitting from ab-initio calculation results

Tags: condensed-matter, electronic-band-theory, tight-binding

Or the problem can be rephrased as: How to extract the tight-binding parameters from first principle calculations?

I have searched some articles but all of them just give vague descriptions when talking about the fitting.

Does any one know how to practically perform the fitting or where to find the methods with details?

Comment: [Density-functional tight-binding for beginners, Koskinen and Makinen 2009](http://users.jyu.fi/~pekkosk/resources/pdf/koskinen_CMS_09.pdf). If memory serves me, some DFT packages even have tight-binding functionality built-in.

Answer (score 1):

After you get the band structure from DFT for your system, make a suitable TB model for your system.

You can analytically solve for the TB parameters. There are multiple ways to fit the model to DFT bands (to solve for parameters).

E.g, If you want to evaluate the Onsite energy differences, Use the DFT energy values at the band splittings to solve the eigenvalues.

If you have ABABABAB..... type of system (Assume same symmetry for A and B), equate the energy values at the Band edge k = Pi/a to the analytical energy eigenvalue expressions at that band edge from the tight binding model. You can do this in mathematica using Solve[] or NSolve[].

Note that there may be a compromise between accuracy of the parameters you evaluate. (Because DFT bands do not exactly match TB band shapes for all systems). If you know what parameters are more important to you, you can fit accordingly.

Hope that helps

Comment: Just noticed that the post was 2 years old.